# How to prevent swagger from spreading nested DTO property

Tags: typescript, swagger, nestjs

I'm creating a query: `@Query() query: AnalyticsRequestDTO<G>` for my GET endpoint that consist of a DTO that looks like this:

```
export class AnalyticsRequestDTO<
        G extends GroupableKeys,
        P extends PopulateableKeys<G> | undefined = undefined
    >
    implements AggregateRunLogAnalyticsOptions<G, P>
{
    @IsObject()
    @IsOptional()
    @ApiProperty({
        description: 'Filters to apply logs',
        required: false,
    })
    filter: AnalyticsFilterDTO = {}

    @IsArray()
    @ApiProperty({
        description: 'The fields to group by',
        required: false,
    })
    groupBy: G[]

    @IsArray()
    @IsOptional()
    @ApiProperty({
        description: 'The fields to populate',
        type: [String],
        required: false,
    })
    populate?: P[]
}
```

The problem here is that the `AnalyticsFilterDTO` is getting spread, like you can see in the next image:
[image: dto property is being spread]

I want to know how to prevent this from happening, as the normal behavior is to send the query wrapped in the filter object (i.e.
{ filter: { ruleId: '...', appId: '..', ... }
). If you send it how swagger suggest, it will fail.

Here's the full controller:

```
@Get('/app/:appId/pages')
    @ApiOperation({
        summary: 'Get rule statistics for all components in an application',
    })
    @ApiResponse({
        description: 'Aggregated analytics',
        type: AnalyticsResultsDTO,
        status: HttpStatus.OK,
    })
    @HttpCode(HttpStatus.OK)
    @ApiQuery({ type: AnalyticsRequestDTO })
    public async getPageRuleStatistics<G extends GroupableKeys>(
        @Param('appId', MongoIdPipe) applicationId: string,
        @Query() query: AnalyticsRequestDTO<G>,
        @Query('forceRebuild', new DefaultValuePipe(false), ParseBoolPipe)
        forceRebuild = false
    ): Promise<AnalyticsResultsDTO<G>> {
        const { filter, groupBy, populate } = query
        // check groupBy
        if (!AnalyticsController.isGroupableKeyArray(groupBy)) {
            throw new BadRequestException(
                'groupBy must be an array of groupable keys'
            )
        }

        const runId = filter['runId']
        if (runId) {
            if (!isMongoId(runId))
                throw new BadRequestException(`Invalid runId ${runId}`)
            await this.analytics.buildRunLogAnalytics(runId, forceRebuild)
        }

        const analytics = await this.analytics.aggregateComponentAnalytics<G>(
            applicationId,
            'page',
            { filter, groupBy, populate }
        )

        return new AnalyticsResultsDTO(analytics)
    }
```

and here's the DTO that is getting spread:

```
export class AnalyticsFilterDTO {
    @IsOptional()
    @IsMongoId()
    @ApiProperty({
        type: String,
        required: false,
    })
    runId?: string | Types.ObjectId

    @IsOptional()
    @IsMongoId()
    @ApiProperty({
        type: String,
        required: false,
    })
    ruleId?: string | Types.ObjectId

    @IsOptional()
    @IsEnum(RuleType)
    @ApiProperty({
        enum: RuleType,
        required: false,
    })
    ruleType?: RuleType

    @IsOptional()
    @IsUUID()
    @ApiProperty({ required: false })
    pageId?: string

    @IsOptional()
    @IsString()
    @ApiProperty({ required: false })
    componentId?: string

    @IsOptional()
    @IsEnum(PageComponentType)
    @ApiProperty({
        enum: PageComponentType,
        required: false,
    })
    componentType?: PageComponentType
}
```

Any idea on how to prevent it?

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using the dto as a query I don't think it's possible to have a nested object.

If you use it in the body of the request you're able to set the property type and this would correctly show the required payload:

```js
@ApiProperty({
    description: 'Filters to apply logs',
    required: false,
    type: AnalyticsFilterDTO,
})
```